# Dovecot+AD not work

Tags: active-directory, debian, dovecot

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 as AD server and Debian Squeeze with Dovecot 1.2.15 as IMAP server. 
When I try to login with telnet, Dovecot is freezing and do nothing.

```
# telnet localhost 143
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot ready.
a LOGIN user pass
* OK Waiting for authentication process to respond..
* BYE Disconnected for inactivity.
```

But if I use wrong user/pass - Dovecot say me about it:

```
# telnet localhost 143
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot ready.
a LOGIN user wrongpass
a NO [UNAVAILABLE] Temporary authentication failure.
```

mail.log (with right login/pass): http://pastebin.com/DTMd8Sh0 (user - mail user, domain.localnet - my domain)

Configs:

dovecot.conf - http://pastebin.com/2C3Ak5k4

dovecot-ldap.conf - http://pastebin.com/nY6KQHCX

Users vmail and postfix are created, vmail:vmail is owner /var/vmail.

aduser and user are created in AD.

Squid, Openfire and Postfix (with bind to AD) successfully works on same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution. Need use static userdb:

```
userdb static {
    args = uid=1001 gid=1001 home=/var/vmail/%u allow_all_users=yes 
 }
```

Comment: Only a question: UID and GID 1001 corresponds to what user and group exactly?

Comment: @RodrigoGuariento vmail:vmail

getent passwd | grep 1001
vmail:x:1001:1001::/home/vmail:/bin/sh